# Why is my TSX component does not work with styled components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm having troubles creating a tsx component with `styled-components`. When using the props `as` it returns this error: `No overload matches this call.`, even though I defined it. How could I fix this?

This is my code:

```
interface styleProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    as?: React.ElementType | keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
}

const Container = styled.button<styleProps>``

const Button: React.FC<{ to: string, children: React.ReactNode }> = props => {
    return (
        <Container as={props.to && Link}>
            {props.children}
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What are you expecting `props.to && Link` to return? Because I'm assuming you didn't intend for it to return a `boolean`? (Which is what it currently does). I'm assuing you meant to use `props.to ?? Link`

Comment: I'm expecting it to return a `Link` (like `<a href="someurl">`) if user adds this prop, and a normal `button` if they don't

Comment: I could fix it by putting `as={props.to ? Link : "button"}`